# Converting mp3 with avconv keeping folder structure

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, avconv, batch

I Have a bunch (~31GB) of mp3 files encoded at 320kbps/cbr and I want to convert them all to mp3 320kbps/vbr keeping it's tags and folder structure but in another master path.

I Would like to use avconv, but any another idea will be welcome.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`? Why do you want to re-encode in the first place?

Comment: Can you give the old folder location as well as the new? This will make examples a little easier...

Comment: /mnt/storage/media/music to /mnt/storage/media/music_vbr

Comment: The use of avconv is optional, I used it more for example than for the real usage, I want to convert them to vbr to save space because my smartphone dont have such space to alocate everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a scriptable method that may be useful:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the old location and the new:
OLD_PATH="$HOME/test"
NEW_PATH="$HOME/alt_location"  

# Create the directory structure in a new location:
find "$OLD_PATH" -type d -exec mkdir -pv "$NEW_PATH{}" \;

# Make the conversion and create the output filename and
# correct path. The cut '-f' setting matches the path
# structure and may need adjustment for your own needs:
find "$OLD_PATH" -type f -iname *.mp3 \
      -exec avconv -i {} -threads 0 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -vn \
      $NEW_PATH$(readlink -f {} | cut -d"/" -f 5-)/{} \;
```

This gives the highest vbr available, some more reading on mp3 settings in my references:

**References:**

- [FFmpeg MP3 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)

Answer (score 1):

I do that installing [TAudioConverter](http://taudioconverter.sourceforge.net/)(is Free Software, GPL2) in wine. This program have the option "Add Folder Tree":

[image]

you only need Add the main folder where you have all your collections:

[image: carpeta principal]

next you chose mp3 in "Presets":

[image: chose mp3]

next chose Codec Options

[image: escojer el codec ejem vbr]

next Start

[image: iniciar]

the place where all files are saved are in HOME in a folder called "TAC":

[image: place for mp3]

Working fine in UbuntuStudio, new mp3 are created in this TAC folder keeping folder structure with the options that you put.

(If you wish convert to other format you can)

The wine version is 1.6

**CAUTION:**

Do not use the option Browse (for the output folders) because not working

[image: No use the option Browse]

Comment: unfortunately its not a option, I am running ubuntu server, just terminal.